# Can't Autowire SessionFactory with Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired

The configuration class name is marked in yellow color and it says `Application context not configured for this file`

> > My Config Class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.tornikeshelia.model");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties(){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect");
    return properties;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8");
    ds.setUsername("username");
    //ds.setPassword("");

    return ds;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

I've commented out `ds.setPassword` because my test database doesn't have any password protection. Also the hibernate doesn't auto create tables from my `Entity` class , I think thats because of this configuration file not being read by Spring

When trying to `autowire` SessionFactor in my `DaoImpl` class via :

```
@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory session;
```

The error says `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tornikeshelia.dao.PersonDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

> > SOLUTION :
> >     The problem was 1)The location of config package and 2) in the warning message that was on the class name (yellowed out with message - `Application context not configured for this file`
> >     So if anybody has same problem here's the solution -
> >
> > 1) move your config package inside the parent package where the model package is
> >
> > 2) Step on the class name (click anywhere on the class name) the yellow light bulb will appear, click on it and then click on `configure application context`, a new tab will appear where you should choose this class and press `okay`.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot or just spring ?

Comment: I'm using just Spring

Comment: And what version of Hibernate? The answers are probably going to be (1) use Boot to configure this and drop your entire manual configuration, (2) use the JPA interface to Hibernate (which is now the recommended one), and (3) use Spring Data JPA to handle all of your data access for you.

Comment: It's definitely better if you can use spring boot but in a legacy application it's not always  easy. If you starting a new application you should consider to use spring boot.

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.5.FINAL

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your config class and update the transationManager() bean :

```
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }
```

Your error may occur because you try to inject a bean that has not bean created yet.

Comment: I edited my error message, your code didn't help . Maybe the error message will clear things